# I have a doubt related to proof that theres only one maximal atlas for an Atlas A. Specifically in the compability of the charts

Tags: differential-geometry

So, lets $A$, be a $C^k-$atlas, and $B$ a set of charts wich each chart is compatible which each chart in A. The thing is that I can take $(V_1,\psi_1),(V_2,\psi_2) \in B$, such that $V_1\cap V_2 \neq \varnothing$. By the definition of $B$, there is $(U,\phi)\in A$ which is compatible with $(V_1,\psi_1),(V_2,\psi_2)$.

This means:

$\phi\circ \psi_{1}^{-1}:\psi_{1}(U\cap V_{1}) \longrightarrow \phi(U\cap V_{1})$

$\psi_2\circ \phi^{-1}:\phi(U\cap V_{2}) \longrightarrow \psi_2(U\cap V_{2})$

So they conclude that, by composition. $\psi_2\circ\psi_1^{-1}$ is $C^k$. But as far as I understand, it would mean that their restriction in $\psi_{1}(U\cap V_1\cap V_2)$ it's so. My teacher told me that it was because of the implicit funcion theorem, but I don't see it really.
So my question is why we can conclude that in fact the compatibility works? If someone help me with that or gives me resource to read, I will realy appreciate it.

Edit: to clarify the question, what I mean is. How can I conclude that $\psi_2\circ\psi_1^{-1}$ with its domain $\psi_1(V_1\cap V_2)$ is in fact $C^k$?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the implicit function theorem.

Comment: Who said there is only one maximal atlas? And what does that have to do with the question? The restriction of any smooth map is smooth.